# Disaster on a ship with crystal computers

Tags: story-identification

Written before 2000, but very likely before 1990.

What I recall is a woman waking up on a ship and discovering that everyone onboard is dead, and the crystal computer system has been corrupted - if I recall correctly, this manifests by the crystals turning black.

She has to find a tiny remaining trace of uncontaminated crystal onboard in order to make the ship function at all - I think - and spends a great deal of time trying to determine what went wrong.

Eventually, she determines that the ship, which had two sections (one for species who could breathe Earth-like air, another for other species with a very different requirement) had undergone a computer malfunction which caused the air supplies to be reversed, killing almost everyone onboard instantly.

Comment: This sounds very similar to a book I've been trying to remember. I thought it had a male captain, but I may be wrong, and that the ship had crashed.